# How to set arabic text to jlable swing?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-platform

when I try to switch between English and Arabic I set Arabic text value that exists in bundle properties file to jlable but the text appear as spaces

Comment: See if the "\uXXXX" representation of unicode characters work.  If yes, you have an encoding problem of your property file.  If no, check if you are using a font with the characters you need available.

Comment: I can use Serbian characters like č, ć, ž, đ, š in JLable, you can use Arabic too.